# Como usar if, elif e else

Tags: python, if, else

> Desafio GOTHAM CITY (nível 1)
>
> Você é um policial e precisa relatar uma atividade criminosa e no
>   relatório você irá dar um número de 0 a 10 a respeito do nível do
>   crime.
>
> Faça um código que receba pelo usuário um número de 0 a 10,
>
> se o número for menor que 5, imprima na tela "Os policiais podem
>   resolver!". Se o número for entre 5 a 8, imprima na tela "Precisamos da
>   ajuda do Batman!". Se o número for maior que 8, imprima na tela "Deixe
>   que o Batman resolva sozinho!".
>
> Anotações:
>
> 1. para que o usuário possa digitar um valor, use a função `input()`
> 2. para que você possa verificar mais de uma condição if, use o `elif` que em Python significa `else if`.

Meu código:

```
n = int(input('De 0 a 10, qual a gravidade do crime?: '))
if n < 5:
    print('Os policiais podem resolver')
elif n >= 5:
    print('Os policiais precisam da ajuda do Batman!')
elif n <= 8:
    print('Os policiais precisam da ajuda do Batman!')
else:
    print('O Batman resolve sozinho!')
```

Onde está o erro no meu código? Empreguei algum uso errado de alguma condição?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 6):

O enunciado diz exatamente o que deve escrever no código, e não está escrito, existem 3 condições estabelecidas e você colocou 4, chega até repetir a mesma ação para duas condições diferentes:

```
n = int(input('De 0 a 10, qual a gravidade do crime?: '))
if n < 5: #se o numero for menor que 5
    print('Os policiais podem resolver')
elif 5 <= n <= 8: #se o numero for entre 5 a 8
    print('Os policiais precisam da ajuda do Batman!')
elif n > 8: #se o numero for maior que 8
    print('O Batman resolve sozinho!')
```

O enunciado não é claro com o que fazer se a pessoa digitar valores inválidos, mas assumi o mesmo que você, se se digitar negativo aceita como se fosse menor que 5 ou se digitar mais que 10 assume que é maior que 8.

Se quiser pode simplificar, mas isso é um tiquinho mais avançado porque não fica óbvio que é para fazer o que o enunciado diz, mas ainda é lógica pura:

```
n = int(input('De 0 a 10, qual a gravidade do crime?: '))
if n < 5: #se o numero for menor que 5
    print('Os policiais podem resolver')
elif n <= 8: #se o numero for menor ou igual a 8, já se sabe que não é menor que 5
    print('Os policiais precisam da ajuda do Batman!')
else: #já se sabe que o número não é menor ou igual a 8, então é maior
    print('O Batman resolve sozinho!')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3M6om5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/RangeConditionspy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Operator/RangeConditions.py).

Por que pode fazer isso? Apenas matemática. Se for menor que 5 cai no primeiro `if` e não executa mais os outros. Se não for menor que 5 pode cair nos outros, mas já é certo que é 5 ou mais, não precisa testar isso de novo. Só precisa garantir que o teto é 8. E finalmente o último só será executado se for maior 8, as condições anteriores garantem isso, não precisa por condição alguma.

Só cai em um `else` quando os `if`s anteriores deram falso, é uma forma de curto circuito, quando dá verdadeiro fecha o circuito e não continua.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Você pode fazer a seguinte estrutura condicional:

```
n = int(input('De 0 a 10, qual a gravidade do crime?: '))

if n < 5:
    print('Os policiais podem resolver')
elif n >= 5 and n <= 8:
    print('Os policiais precisam da ajuda do Batman!')
else:
    print('O Batman resolve sozinho!')
```

Comment: aaaa entendi, então basicamente era só colocar o and ali...eu tinha pensado em deixar em apenas três condições mas n sabia como deixar entre 5 e 8 acabei criando uma condição a mais q fez o programa ficar estranho... obrigado!

Comment: Neste caso o `and` é redundante. Para testar range em Python basta isso: `5 <= n <= 8` (que no caso nem é necessário nesse exercício, o primeiro `if` ja elimina tudo que for menor que 5)

Answer (score 0):

Validando os valores de entrada de 0 a 10 e o if / elif / else proposto.

```
num_crime = -1
while not int(num_crime) in range(0,11):
    num_crime = input('Informe a gravidade do crime (0 - 10) : ')

if int(num_crime) < 5:
    print('Os policiais podem resolver')
elif int(num_crime) <= 8:
    print('Os policiais precisam da ajuda do Batman!')
else:
    print('O Batman resolve sozinho!')
```

Abs,